# Where a question merely asks about a word's etymology, should it be asked here or on English.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

Some questions ask about the etymology of a word that happens to be used in law, but where there is nothing special about the word's use in law.

Is the mere fact that a word is used in law enough to make an etymology question on-topic here? Or should such questions be asked at English.SE instead?

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, here and there

Providing it has a specific legal meaning, exclusively or in parallel with generic meanings, it’s [on topic](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

It’s also on topic there. Questions can have more than one home.